# gethostbyname freezes and uses 100% CPU on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, sockets, unix, gethostbyname

I have a program which opens a few sockets to listen and send on.  I've found a very strange condition, so-far only on Mac OS X, where `gethostbyname` completely freezes the program.

Firstly, I am *not* using threads.  Secondly, the problem only happens if I run *two* copies of my test program at once.

The first instance creates 4 sending and 4 receiving sockets, and then they commence sending traffic to each other.  In the network library I am using for messaging, `gethostbyname()` is called just after the receiving port is opened.  I found that when I started a second instance of the test program, after opening 3 receivers, the last one just stuck there.

I've narrowed the problem down to the call to `gethostbyname`, which seemingly *never returns*.  (Keep in mind that it worked fine for every call to `gethostbyname` up to this point.)  Also, when it hits this point, suddenly the CPU usage of the test program jumps to 100%, as if there is an infinite loop in `gethostbyname`.  Additionally I can't Ctrl-C the process, I have to kill it from another terminal.

Obviously this behaviour is unacceptable, even if it only occurs in this extreme case of starting 8 sender/receiver pairs.  (4 in once process, 4 in another.)  Has anyone seen this before and how can I avoid it?

By the way the only other platform tested is Linux (Ubuntu 10.04), where it runs just fine.

Comment: Does this problem occur on all Macs, or just one?  If the latter, perhaps that Mac has some kind of networking configuration problem.

Comment: I've only tested on one mac.. thanks for the suggestion, I will try on another.

Comment: Can we see your code? The other day I had a bug that appeared to be read() blocking indefinitely but was actually an infinite loop elsewhere. If CPU jumps to 100% it sounds like you have an infinite non-blocking loop too.

Comment: It could be your nameserver service on that platform is bugged. If it works on another OS that indicates a probable cause.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have been stung by this [Oracle Java Bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7180557). My workaround was to add the hostname of my Mac to /etc/hosts

```
sudo bash -c "echo 127.0.0.1 $HOSTNAME >> /etc/hosts"
```